# Java webservice monitoring (charts)

Tags: java, web-services, monitoring

I'm looking for a tool allowing monitoring of webservices uptime/response time. I'm interested in two particular groups:

1. Monitoring external calls in an existing application: something which would show response times for all external calls.
2. Monitoring just the webservices: an application which would periodically query given webservice(s) with prepared requests and record response time.

In both cases I'd like to get some charts and basic reports (avg/min/max response time at least). Which tools should I look at, what would you suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jmeter could help you. Please refer following link
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html